# mySQL - Sum columns in a table based on one field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in my database that's structured as such:

```
Week  Team   Player     Plants  Score  Ball Kills
1     Team1  Player1.1   1        1      1   
1     Team1  Player1.2   2        1      0   
1     Team2  Player2.1   0        4      3   
1     Team2  Player2.2   3        1      5   
2     Team1  Player1.1   2        7     11  
2     Team1  Player1.2   2        2      0   
2     Team2  Player2.1   0        0      1   
2     Team2  Player2.2   2        1      1
```

I'm trying to output a table where I sum all the fields of the table based on a Player (E.g. sum all the values for Player1.1 to get the total for each column)

So for instance:

/ Team / / Player / / Plants / / Score / / Ball Kills /.....
/ Team1 / / Player1.1 / / 3 / / 8 / / 12 /.....
/ Team1 / / Player1.2 / / 4 / / 3 / / 0 /.....
/ Team2 / / Player2.1 / / 0 / / 4 / / 4 /.....
/ Team2 / / Player2.2 / / 5 / / 2 / / 6 /.....

This is the code I have so far. Obviously it just outputs the entire table.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Table1";
$Data = mysql_query ($sql,$con);

echo '<table class="db-table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

<tr>
<th>Team</th>
<th>Player</th>
<th>Plants</th>
<th>Ball Kills</th>
<th>First Touch</th>
<th>Fast Break</th>
<th>Runner Score</th>
<th>Tank Score</th>
<th>Defender Score</th>

</tr>';
while ($results = mysql_fetch_array ($Data)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $results['Team'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $results['Player'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $results['Plants'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $results['Ball Kills'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $results['First Touch'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $results['Fast Break'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $results ['Runner Score'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $results['Tank Score'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $results['Defender Score'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

I've looked at many examples of my problem, however it doesn't do what I want when I put the code in, and I can't figure out why. I am new to php, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: For starters, you need a closing double quotes for $sql. Also, do you have a php error log? If so, do you have any errors or warnings?

Comment: Sorry, yes there is a closing double quote in my actual quote, I just editted the table name on here. This code does work and does output the entire table properly.

Comment: Use SUM on the last 3 columns and GROUP BY Player

Comment: I've added SUM (Plants) SUM (Score) SUM (Balls Kills) GROUP BY Player, however nothing shows up now.

Comment: `SELECT player, SUM (Plants) Plants, SUM (Score) Score, SUM (Balls Kills) 'Ball Kills' FROM Table1 GROUP BY player` Use an alias to correspond with the $results calls.

Comment: I did that exactly, however same thing. Nothing shows.

And I'm not quite sure what you mean by use an alias with the $results calls? Sorry. I'm really new to php.

Comment: $results['Score']  calls column Score so when you use SUM(Score) it changes the name.Alias it`s just another name,SUM(Score) as Score,without it the column name its SUM(Score) so you`s have to call it $results['SUM(Score)']

Comment: Oh, I understand. Thanks.

I did add that in, it's still not working.

Comment: Add the other columns to the queries.

Comment: Yes, I did. This is what I have now:

`$sql = "SELECT player, SUM (Team) AS Team, SUM (Plants) AS Plants, SUM (Ball Kills) AS 'Ball Kills', SUM (First Touch) AS 'First Touch', SUM (Fast Break) AS 'Fast Break', SUM (Runner Score) AS 'Runner Score', SUM (Tank Score) AS 'Tank Score', SUM (Defender Score) AS 'Defender Score' FROM EUGBL17FLPlayerData GROUP BY player";`

Comment: But in the original query it worked?Use this query in phpmyadmin to make sure it works.

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM EUGBL17FLPlayerData";`

Did work originally, yes. I tested it, and it worked.

Comment: I've even simplified my table down right now to just display Player and Plants, and now have `$sql = "SELECT Player, SUM (Plants) AS 'Plants' FROM EUGBL17FLPlayerData GROUP BY Player";`, and it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one query using `group by`

```
select
t.Team,
t.Player,
sum(t.Plants) as Plants,
sum(t.Score) as Score,
sum(t.`Ball Kills`) as `Ball Kills`
from table1 t1
group by 
t.Team,
t.Player
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT
t.Team,t.Player,sum(t.'Ball Kills') as 'Ball Kills',sum(t.Plants) as plants,
sum(t.Score) as Score
FROM Table1 t
GROUP BY Team,player
ORDER BY 'Ball Kills',plants
```